# VB ListBox list ftp directories and remove multiple lines based on number in folder name

Tags: vb.net, loops, combobox, ftp, listboxitem

I do get a lot of help from this website searching for a solution but at this point I'm completely stuck. I'm not a programmer, still was able to get that far.
The idea of my little project is to download newest version of a program (folder) from FTP server. Unzip files and update current program folder with new files. But before that backup the exiting program folder to a different FTP address.

What I'm struggling with is a way they post program versions (folders) on FTP:
[folder structure on FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lwX1.png)
I can't really predict what would be the next folder to download because e.g. for program version:
`7.6.16`
it might be:
`WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.6.17`
or
`WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.7.01`
what ever is being released.

There is an ini file on C drive that holds the current program version. I was able to retrieve that information by reading the line, removing the unnecessary characters and splitting the string:

```
Dim wersja1 As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Windows\file.ini").FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("WERSJA="))
Dim characterToRemove1 As String = "WERSJA="
Dim wersja2 As String = Replace(wersja1, characterToRemove1, "")
Dim characterToRemove2 As String = "T"
Dim wersja3 As String = Replace(wersja2, characterToRemove2, "")
Dim wersja4 As String() = wersja3.Split(New Char() {"."c})
Dim w1 As String = wersja4(0)
Dim w2 As String = wersja4(1)
Dim w3 As String = wersja4(2)
```

e.g. from a line:
`WERSJA=7.6.5T`
I get:
`w1 = 7
w2 = 6
w3 = 5`
Then I change the last one (w3) to a two digits number ([because of the way folders are named on FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISSVt.png)):

```
If w3 < 10 Then
    w3 = "0" & w3
Else
    w3 = w3
End If
```

So if:
`w3 = 5 >> I get 05
w3 = 16 >> I get 16`

So far, so good.

***In the next step I would like to see a filtered list of program versions (folders) in a ListBox or 2 ListBoxes. I would like to filter the list to see only folder with a bigger number than the current program version, so I can choose the correct one to download.***

Why this way? Because if current version is e.g.
`7.6.16`
and there are 3 new ones e.g.:
`7.6.17
7.6.18
7.7.01`
***I need to download all of them one by one, update program files and start the program to update sql database in order they were released. I can't skip any version on update.***

```
Dim FTPurl As String = "ftp://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/wersje/"
Dim FTPwersja As String = "WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_*"
Dim FTPlog As String = "xxx"
Dim FTPpass As String = "yyy"

Dim clsRequest As FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(FTPurl & FTPwersja)
clsRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FTPlog, FTPpass)
clsRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
Dim listResponse As FtpWebResponse = clsRequest.GetResponse
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(listResponse.GetResponseStream())

'folder list
While reader.Peek >= 0
    ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine)
End While

'remove empty lines
For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next i
```

The above code gives me [this result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLHMN.png)
***I found this code that enables filtering of ListBox but I have no clue on how to convert it to an loop so I would see only folders with bigger numbers than the current version of program:***

```
'filter result in list box
Dim items = From it In ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)()
    Where it.ToString().IndexOf("7.5", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
Dim matchingItemList As List(Of Object) = items.ToList()
ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
'ListBox1.Items.Clear() 'add to list
For Each item In matchingItemList
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(item) 'remove from list
    'ListBox1.Items.Add(item) 'add to list
Next
ListBox1.EndUpdate()
```

I also have this code to catch choice and prevent crash when clicked on empty line :

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
Try
    Dim LB1choice = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Label5.Text = LB1choice
Catch ex As Exception
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Try
End Sub
```

The ideal would be 2 ComboBoxes where 1st would display e.g.
`WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.6
WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.7`
and based on the choice 2nd ComboBox would list newer subfolders in it e.g.
`WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.6.16
WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.6.17`
for the 1st one, and:
`WERSJA_NOWY_TEMPLATE_7.7.01`
for the 2nd one.
***I much appreciate if anyone could help me this because it's beyond my skills.***

Comment: This question is way too long. That fact demonstrates that you haven't really focused on a specific issue. If the question is how to get a version number from the end of a specifically formatted `String` then that is what you should have asked as nothing about `ListBoxes` or FTP is relevant to that. A bit of background is OK but rambling just obfuscates the actual problem.

Comment: Those example `Strings` you have provided indicate that you could just split the `String` on the underscores, take the last substring and then create a [`Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.version.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Version__ctor_System_String_) object from it. You can then compare those `Version` objects to see which is the latest.